# Eigenvalues problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume one knows the eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)$ of a real matrix $M$ of size $n \times n$. Let $b$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and construct the following matrix $J$ by:
$$J_{ij} = M_{ij}b_j$$
Can we deduce the eigenvalues of $J$ from the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and the vector $b$ ?

Comment: J is a vector...

Comment: @percusse : no i think J is a matrix

Comment: Okay, so you're postmultiplying $M$ with the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(b)$... I would say there doesn't seem to be a nice relationship between the eigenvalues of that and the eigenvalues of your original matrix...

Comment: To make it clearer what $J$ is, you could write $$J=M\mathrm{diag}(\vec{b}).$$

Comment: [A related question...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58252)

Comment: @mellow It was a little bit puzzling for me since $b$ is a vector. I see that you are not summing over indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, suppose $n=2$ and we know that $M$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $2$ and that $b=(1,0)$. Then we might have $M=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, in which case $J=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $2$. On the other hand, we might have $M=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, in which case $J=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ has $0$ as its only eigenvalue.