# the eigenvalues of product of matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix with positive eigenvalues and $B$ be a positive definite matrix . How to estimate the minimum eigenvalues of $AB$ by using the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. More precisely, are there some inequalities such as $\min\{\lambda(AB)\}\geq\min\{\lambda(A),\lambda(B)\}$? Here $\lambda(A)$ denotes the eigenvalue of $A$. Thank you.

Comment: Posted also at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125836/the-eigenvalues-of-product-of-matrices

Comment: So you see the sidebar entitled "Related" on the right? [The first question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20302/eigenvalues-of-product-of-a-matrix-and-a-diagonal-matrix?rq=1) it lists seems relevant.