# eigenvalues of a matrix and its product with a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-congruences

There is a similar question to mine posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20302/eigenvalues-of-product-of-a-matrix-and-a-diagonal-matrix).

I have a matrix $L$ which is the graph Laplacian of a strongly connected normal graph. Therefore, $L$ is normal, has a simple eigenvalue at zero, and all its other eigenvalues have positive real parts.

Is there a way to express the eigenvalues of the product $DL$, (with $D>0$ a diagonal matrix) in terms of those of $L$ and $D$?

I found the following hints so far:

- the spectra of $DL$ and $D^{1/2}LD^{1/2}$ are identical
- $L$ and $D^{1/2}LD^{1/2}$ are congruent, and by Sylvester's law of inertia (extended to normal matrices), they have the same number of positive real part, negative real part and zero eigenvalues
- The [accepted answer to a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20302/eigenvalues-of-product-of-a-matrix-and-a-diagonal-matrix) cites a paper on Horn's inequalities, but the paper is very advanced, and it is not clear how (and whether) its results apply to my question. Please note that $L$ is not necessarily symmetric in my case.