Bounding Eigenvalues of Product of Real Matrix and Diagonal Matrix
I have a real matrix  $\mathbf{H} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda^H_1, \ldots, \lambda^H_n$, and a diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D} = \mathrm{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_n)$. Let $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_n$ be the eigenvalues of the product $\mathbf{H}\mathbf{D}$. I want to understand two cases:

$\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_n \in [-1,0]$

$\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_n > 0$


Is it possible to guarantee case 1 and 2 given the following conditions on $\mathbf{H}, \mathbf{D}$:
(a) for case 1: $\lambda^H_1, \ldots, \lambda^H_n \in [-1,0]$, for case 2: $\lambda^H_1, \ldots, \lambda^H_n > 0$
(b) for case 1: $d_1, \ldots, d_n \in [0,1]$, for case 2: $d_1, \ldots, d_n > 0$
If so, why is this true?
I know from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20315 that if $\mathbf{H}$ is symmetric positive semi-definite and $\mathbf{D}$ is positive then it is possible to obtain bounds of the form $\mu_k \leq \lambda^H_id_j$ and  $\mu_{k'} \geq \lambda^H_id_j$. However, I want to avoid assuming symmetry in $\mathbf{H}$ at all costs. Is this possible? If not, is there another condition (apart from symmetry in $\mathbf{H}$) I can add?

the answer is no-- you cannot even expect all eigenvalues to be real under these conditions.   Let $H$ be the $3 \times 3$ companion matrix having all eigenvalues $=1$ and let $D$ be the identity matrix with the first component modified, say to $0.8$ then neither $DH$ nor $D(-H)$ have purely real eigenvalues and the real part does not have modulus bounded by $1$.  Eigenvalues of products of matrices are rarely tractable unless there is a lot of structure (e.g. commutativity or symmetry).
